# Toggle between relative and absolute Import of built in module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

So I have the script that imports the standard module checkmarc.

```
import checkdmarc
```

I want to implement some mock checkmarc that will seat at the same directory as the script.
Now sometime it will be there and I want the script to pull that local module and if it's not there it should take the standard checkmarc.
I know I can do something like if the file in the path exists it'll take that, else do that, but I want to keep the import line just `import checkmarc`.

From reading: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328-absolute-and-relative-imports
there's a section of exactly what I need but only for Python 2.4 and lower:

> In Python 2.4 and earlier, it will first
>   look in the package’s directory to perform a relative import, finds
>   pkg/string.py, imports the contents of that file as the pkg.string
>   module, and that module is bound to the name string in the pkg.main
>   module’s namespace.

If there's an elegant way to do it, I'd love to hear.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this if your custom module has the same name. You can however do something like this:

```
try:
    import customcheckdmarc as checkdmarc
except ImportError:
    import checkdmarc as checkdmarc
```

this will load your customecheckedmarc.py if it's there and will load default checkdmarc otherwise.